# Is there a better way to convert tokens to features in Python?

Tags: python

I wrote a Python function following a pseudo-code to convert tokens to features. What it does is to return the most-appeared k tokens. I am wondering if there is any better/nicer way to write the function.

```
def token2feature(k,ts): #k is number of desired features; ts is a list of all tokens
   import operator
   hs={} #create an empty dictionary
   for tok in ts:
       hs[tok] =hs[tok]+1 if tok in hs else 1
   sorted_hs=sorted(hs.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
   return dict(sorted_hs[:k]).keys()
```

Edited:
Input is a list of tokens

```
ts=['a','b','a','a','b'','c']
k=2
```

Output is the most occurred k elements in the list.

```
['a','b']
```

Comment: You did not explain what you expect the function to do. Please also give sample input and output.

Comment: What are "features"?

Comment: @jamesdlin Here they are the most occurred k words/tokens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def token2feature(k, ts):
   return [t for t, c in Counter(ts).most_common(k)]

print(token2feature(2, ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b'])) #=> ['a', 'b']
```

From documentation:

> A **Counter** is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, according the benchmark test   http://evanmuehlhausen.com/simple-counters-in-python-with-benchmarks/       'Counter' performs worst and 'defaultdict' performs best. The blog was published in 2012. Not sure if there's any improvement now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `k` is "top k", and `ts` are the items you are counting

You are probably looking for the `most_common` method of [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter as at
def token2feature(k, ts):
    return map(at(0), Counter(hs).most_common(k))
```